# How to use hardened key derivation properly?

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, private-key, ethereumjs, hd-wallets

I am implementing a wallet for customers' deposits account. I am using `ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey`. I need to decide which derivation path to use:

standard for ethereum would be `m/44'/60'/0'/0` but maybe I'd rather use a custom path as the wallet is for ethereum exclusive so I could at least use  `m/44'/60'/0'` because no UTXO and no need for change addresses.

Currently I'm struggling because can not find a method to derive hardened children.

Do I understand it correctly, if children are not hardened, than any leaked child private key would compromise all the siblings and parents?

Is there a possibility to create hardened children with ethereumjs-wallet?

Answer (score 1):

The more common path used in popular wallets is m/44'/60'/0'/0, so the first available address become m/44'/60'/0'/0/0. I see no benefit using a different path, the strength of the key is derived from the seed and not from the path.

Having a child key does not allow generation of the parent key. The security of the child key derivation relies on the security of HMAC-SHA512 algorithm. To derive the parent from the child you have to somehow be able to reverse that algorithm.

I'd suggest to consult with [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) to understand how the HD wallets are generated.